# Is it possible to remove text from under the icons on the home screen?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, launcher, customization, motorola-moto-g, app-icons

I'm familiar with all the icons on my home screen. I think it would look better, at least to me, if the text from under those icons is gone. Is this possible?

I'm willing to root my device for this, but not switch to an alternate home screen launcher app.

I am using Moto-G with Kit Kat.

Comment: You could install a different launcher, Nova Launcher has this functionality under Nova settings > Dock > Remove Dock Icon Labels or similar... The same for the desktop icons also.

Comment: He's not willing to use another launcher, @RossC

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done on the Google launcher itself . But you will have to root your phone. You will not only be able to hide the text but be able to tweak even more stuff. But let's just stick to hiding the text for now.

Download [Xposed GEL Settings](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.theknut.xposedgelsettings)

It is an xposed module and requires the xposed framework. If you don't know what that is, here's a video to get you started off with the  [Android Xposed Framework](http://youtu.be/mey906089P4).

If you still have questions, do ask.

Comment: I looked all over for an Xposed mod but couldn't find one anywhere to do it. Good find.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://market.android.com/details?id=com.abcOrganizer.lite&feature=search_result

Once installed, long press on homescreen to add a shortcut, add a "FolderOrganiser" app shorcut and it asks you whether you want to "add text below" icon.

Answer (score 0):

Found one way around this. I only tested this with GO Launcher that supports renaming apps.
If you tap + hold the app icon, then tap "Rename", it allows you to erase the name then save it without a name. I found this to be the easiest, lightest way without having to download additional apps that are overbearing with stuff we really weren't looking for to fix our problem.